# All images are loaded immediately with lazySizes plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, lazy-loading

I have a problem with my dynamic integration of Lazysizes plugin. 
The fact is when I load the page (cache disable), all images of the src are loaded with the content. 
After this, responsives images are lazy-loaded like I want.

My reflection :

- I replace src attribute with a small image - but browser keeps to load original images before change src with this small image.
- all images aren't display in the viewport when the page load because I use the padding ratio trick for each of them.
- I tried to move my script in the header of the page, but nothing change.

Here my jquery script at the bottom of the page :

```
//lazy init
window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
lazySizesConfig.loadMode = 2;   
lazySizesConfig.preloadAfterLoad = false;
$('img').addClass('lazyload');

$("img.lazyload").each(function() { 
    var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg$/i, "");
    $(this).attr("data-sizes","auto"); 
    $(this).attr("data-srcset", 
      src + '-240.jpg 240w,' + 
      src + '-360.jpg 360w,' + 
      src + '-480.jpg 480w, ' + 
      src + '-720.jpg 720w,' + 
      src + '-768.jpg 768w,' + 
      src + '-960.jpg 960w,' + 
      src + '-1280.jpg 1280w'
    ); 
    $(this).attr(
       "src",
       "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
    );
});
```

I would like only responsive img is load when it is in the viewport.
any idea about my issue  ?

thanks

Comment: I'm not shure about your issue but do you try play with `$(document).ready(function(){...});` and `$(document).on("change","img",function(){...});` ???

Comment: Currently my script is in a `$(document).ready` - I need the content of src attribute for the responsive part of my script but I realize I would like to remove it before page load. There is a confusion. Maybe I need too write a php script but I am novice in this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having is caused by the fact, that you're using JavaScript, to set the `data-sizes` and `data-srcset` attributes.

lazySizes script expects you to specify all of that in your HTML output.

You have to make sure that jQuery will be loaded, and your script will be executed before `lazysizes.js`.

I can't guarantee for any of my advice below to be useful, because this script is not intended to be used like that. Still, if you **really want to get it to work with jQuery script from your question**, consider the following:

1. Remove `async` attribute from lazysizes `<script>` tag.
2. Set `lazySizesConfig.preloadAfterLoad = true;`
3. Run your script right after jQuery is loaded, doesn't matter where you put the script, just make sure it's executed before lazySizes and on `$(document).ready()`.
4. Only if all above is done, the lazySizes should lazyload the images as expected.

Comment: So I need to write my script with a server-side language like php. Right ?

Comment: Currently, I use Lazysize with Jquery in the same way of your description. Img are lazy-loaded but my script replace src attribute after page load. this is the problem. I will try the php way...

Answer (score 0):

1. You first need to specify data- atributtes.
2. Load HTML
3. Load jQuery and lazysizes.js
4. Get all data- and save in variable
5. Handle with it

I don't know if lazysizes.js have inside script some document ready function or some DOM change sniffer but I think you need a different approach.